# Lotus Notes - Document does not shows in view BUT when i do a search it comes up

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotus, lotus-formula, notesview

I have a Lotus Notes database in which a view shows up empty, BUT when i do a search (using basic notes search functionality), it returns some documents. How can this be possible? Also how to make those documents show up in the view.

I tried updating the Readers field of the documents, but that also didn't worked.

Please help.

Comment: you may want to expand your question a little bit.. there's big number of reasons for which documents in specific view are not listed..

Comment: Where are you performing the "search using basic Notes functionality"? From the same view? as the same user? Are the resulting documents "response" documents? (You can check if the field list on document properties for a document contains $Ref).  I don't think the problem is related to security (reader fields, ...) if you see the documents using same Notes user id.

Comment: Ed's suggestion, that you might be finding orphaned response documents is a good possibility.  If you don't have your view set up to show response hierarchy, the orphans won't be shown even if they meet the selection formula.  If that's not it, then what is the selection formula for your view?  And what exactly is the "basic Notes search functionality" that you are talking about?  Is it a search formula?  A full text search?

Comment: search using basic notes functionality is searching the view in the client.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is very high probability your view shows response documents, but not their parent/main document. Response hierarchy is ignored after FT search, therefore they show up.

Simply, turn off "Show response documents in a hierarchy" in view properties or rewrite selection formula.

Answer (score 1):

First check if the view is actually empty. You could have documents in the view, but because they don't have fields that match the columns they won't be visible.

Double click on a blank spot where a document should be, or CTRL-A (Select All). Alternatively page down a number of times, as the documents you are finding may be lower down.

I would recommend then to check the Search criteria of the view in question that you are not accidentally pulling in documents that are not meant for that view.

If that doesn't work (which I have never seen to be honest), the full text index search works as follows.

1. Make a call to the FTI folder with the search term.
2. Gets a list of documents that match the search.
3. Discards the documents on that list based on the following.

   - Is the user allowed to view the document?
   - Would the document appear in the view under normal circumstances?
   - Has the document since been deleted?
   - (Forth reason escapes me, will look it up)
4. It then displays those documents in the view.

So in short, the full text index search will never show documents that cannot already be shown in the view.

Beyond that, a possible corrupted view index. You can run "UPDALL -v" on it to rebuild the indexes.

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/topic/com.ibm.help.domino.admin85.doc/H_UPDALL_OPTIONS_3277_STEPS.html